# Algorithm to find pair with max sum from two arrays

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, array

Algorithm to find pair with max sum from two arrays

```
A[0 ... n] and B[0 ... n]
A[i] + B[j] = max (A[i] + B[j], with i < j) 
i,j < 99999; n < 99999
```

My best result is this:

```
int[] testArrayA = { 7, 1, 4, 5, 1};
int[] testArrayB = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 3};
String res = "";
int maxSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < testArrayA.length; i++)
{
    int i1 = testArrayA[i];
    for (int j = i; j < testArrayB.length; j++)
    {
        int j1 = testArrayB[j];
        if((j1 + i1) > maxSum)
        {
            maxSum = j1 + i1;
            res = i + " " + j;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Expected answer "0 3"
Current complexity \$O(n^2)\$ I think it must be much lower. Can we do it better?

Comment: Yes, this can be done a lot faster. Welcome to Code Review! One of the Java guys will probably tell you exactly what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can solve this in \$O(n)\$ time. The best possible sum for a particular index, \$i\$, is \$S[i] = A[i] + \max(B[i+1:])\$ (using the Python notion of slice). We can update both incrementally by counting from the back, so we have to keep track of two things: \$\max(S[i:])\$ and \$\max(B[i+1:])\$.

So for the test arrays:

```
int[] testArrayA = { 7, 1, 4, 5, 1};
int[] testArrayB = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 3};
                              ↑
                              starting i
```

At `i==3`, we start with `maxS == 8` and `maxB == 3`, since those are the only two options. With `i==2`, we update `maxB = max(maxB, B[i+1]) = 5` and `maxS = max(maxS, A[i] + maxB) = max(8, 4+5) = 9`. etc.

In code:

```
public static void printMaxIncreasingIndexSum(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    int bIdx = B.length - 1;
    int aIdx = A.length - 2;

    int maxB = bIdx;
    int maxS = A[A.length - 2] + B[maxB];

    for (int i = A.length - 3; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (B[i+1] > B[maxB]) {
            maxB = i+1;
        }

        if (A[i] + B[maxB] > maxS) {
            maxS = A[i] + B[maxB];
            aIdx = i;
            bIdx = maxB;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("%d %d", aIdx, bIdx);
}
```